# vertical alignment of anchors and input groups in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to line up the following components so that their middle's are centered. I cannot figure out which CSS property is causing the buttons to be lower.

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="/create" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="fa fa-codepen"></span>New</a>
    <a href="/upload" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-open"></span>Upload</a>
    <a href="/download" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>Download</a>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <div class="input-group" style="width:20em">
            <input style="" class="form-control focus" id="Search" name="Search" type="search">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn default btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="rc.search()">Search</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MG2xUvxvR9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/MG2xUvxvR9#

The input group needs to be wrapped within a `form-group` tag. And then I wrapped the entire thing in a `form-inline`.

Comment: I tried your advice [here](http://www.bootply.com/wDalEsWsQv#), but it seems to have made the alignment worse.
I would also like to know which part of the CSS is causing this alignment issue. I have tried debugging it, and cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: ok, I see my mistake, you are correct, the form-inline does [solve the problem](http://www.bootply.com/Gk8mk9F1B9). I would really like to know what CSS property is causing this, do you have any ideas?

Comment: In order for the input group to have proper alignment it needs to be wrapped in a form-group, that's how it works. Annoying, but it does solve the trick. Please let me know if this solves your problem.